# Adding HTML from JS doesn't work

Tags: javascript, html, innerhtml, listeners

I'm using some ready HTML for color picker.
When I add it in HTML, It works.
But when I add from javascript (after clicking button) as innerHTML It doesn't works.
As I saw, when HTML is starting some listeners (or maybe other things) are adding automathicaly.
What Can I do?

code JSP:

```
<html>
   <head>
      <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
      <title>Insert title here</title>
      <%--color picker --%>
      <script type="text/javascript" src="jscolor.js"></script>
      <script type="text/javascript">
         function add() {
            document.body.innerHTML += "<input id=\"zaz1\" size=\"5\" class=\"color\" value=\"000000\"> ";
         }
      </script>
   </head>
   <body>
      <input id="zaz" size="5" class="color" value="000000">
      <p onclick="add()">add</p>
   </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Give some sample code, please

Comment: Well does the color picker have a method to initlaize the widgets? If so you will need to call it.

Comment: Rather than append to the body, would you not be better creating a div to contain the new content, and reference it by class or ID? For example: document.getElementById("the-new-div").innerHTML = "value";

Comment: try this: `<p onclick="javascript:add()">add</p>` and in the function `add()` put an aler right at the beginning to see if the function is being called: `function add() {
                alert('called function');
                document.body.innerHTML += "<input id=\"zaz1\" size=\"5\" class=\"color\" value=\"000000\"> ";
            }`

Comment: I agree with Graham's comment. This is not the best way to do it, however when I throw it in a fiddle and a blank page the code you posted does add the input boxes with 000000 to the page. So what is not working for you?

Comment: Also seems to be working with copying your exact code as a HTML file, I can't reproduce your problem. Which browser are you using?

Comment: This piece of html/javascript works without jscolor.js, so i'll guess that jscolor.js has some errors/missing libraries?. Look at your console and see if anything is red when you launch this.

By any chance doesn't jscolor.js need something like jquery ?

Answer (score 0):

Okay i understand why this doesn't work.

You need the images that was contained in the jscolor zip.

So put jscolor.js, your htlm files, and all given images in the same folder.

When you have that kind of error look at your console in the developper tools of your browser, my browser specifically told me what files were missing.